$S^3$ to describe three-vectors
In this wiki article about topological defects ( see the "To restate more plainly..." paragraph is remarked that a $3$- sphere $S^3$ can be used to encode a three-vector, its direction plus length.
Could somebody elaborate this part? Why do we actually need $S^3$ and not naively guessed $\Bbb R^3$ to encode a three-vecor? It seems that there is something in this description in this part about description of three- vectors I not understand. What is actually meant there in the quoted sentence?

Previous paragraph: "[...] one-point compactification: adding a point at infinity. This is reasonable, as one is generally interested in solutions that vanish at infinity, and so are single-valued at that point."

Keep in mind that parys of Wikipedia articles are frequently written by people with very limited understanding of the subject. This, I think, is one of those cases.

@coiso: but that's strage as on would (hopefully) expect that some homotopy classes are nontrivial: So we want to have maps (=solution of the PDE) $f: S^3 \to S^3$ with identification $S^3= \Bbb R^3 \cup {\infty}$ (=latter: point at infinity) and this is justified by that on "affine part" $f$ maps from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$ and subjected to additional condition that $f$ "vanish at infinity", so we can extend $f$ to $S^3$ by setting $f(\infty)=0 \in \Bbb R^3$. But isn't this

absurd as the the image of $f$ would be then contained in $\Bbb R^3 \subset S^3$ and so $f$ would be contractible, to the theory from homotopical side useless, so not what we want. Or do I commiting a thinking error here? Not sure, but presumably that's exactly that kind absurdness in this excerpt that @Moise Kohan intended to single out.
